# ImportError: cannot import name 'CRS' from 'pyproj'?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyproj, importerror

I have installed pyproj version 1.9.6. using the command prompt window. However, when trying to import CRS (from pyproj import CRS), I receive the following ImportError:

ImportError: cannot import name 'CRS' from 'pyproj' (C:\Users\snn490\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\CoInf\lib\site-packages\pyproj__init__.py)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The pyproj.CRS class was introduced in version 2. You will need to upgrade pyproj to use it.